# can't attach topic_id in the comment table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am making a forum where users can create topics and leave a reply just like this forum.

I made a relationship just like below.However, when I save an article the topic_id does not get attached.I think the saveReply method is wrong.

Also,in this case how do you pass comments on the particular post to the view in the show method??

I am a noob,so if my question is vague I am sorry,but any help will be appreciated!!

Route

```html
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::get('forums','ForumsController@index');
    Route::get('forums/create','ForumsController@create');
    Route::post('forums', 'ForumsController@store');
    Route::get('forums/{category_id}/{title}','ForumsController@show');
    Route::post('forums/{category_id}/{title}', 'ForumsController@saveReply');

});
```

forumcontroller

```html
class ForumsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
     $categories = Category::all();
     $topics = Topic::latest()->get();
       return view('forums.index',compact('categories','topics'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
      $categories = Category::lists('title', 'id');
       return view('forums.create', compact('categories'));
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
      Auth::user()->topics()->save(new Topic($request->all()));

       flash()->success('投稿しました','success');

       return redirect('forums');
    }
       

    public function show($category_id, $title)
    {
       Topic::where(compact('category_id','title'))->first();

       



       return view('forums.post', compact('topic'));
    }

     public function saveReply (Request $request)
    {
       Auth::user()->comments()->save(new Comment($category_id,$request->all()));


       flash()->success('投稿しました','success');

       return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

topic model

```html
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class topic extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
     'title',
     'body',
        'category_id'
     ];

    public function category()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\category');
    }

    public function user()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function comments()
    {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
}
```

user model

```html
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function articles()
    {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Article');
    }

    public function topics()
    {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Topic');
    }

    public function comments()
    {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
}
```

comment model

```html
class Comment extends Model
{
 protected $fillable = [
    'reply',
    'user_id',
    'topic_id'
  ];


    public function topic()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Topic');
    }

    public function user()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

comment table

```html
class CreateCommentsTable extends Migration
{
        public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->text('reply');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();

            $table->integer('topic_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('comments');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Request::all` returns an array of all inputs so when you are doing:

```
new Comment($category_id,$request->all())
```

You'll get something like this:

```
1['some' => 'thing', 'other'=> 'values']
```

Which could be the problem so try this instead:

```
new Comment(array_merge(['category_id' => $category_id ], $request->all())
```

When on development/local environment, set the `debug` true so you'll get meaningful error messages so you can findout the exect problem easily.